# How can I configure DbSet with an ICollection<T> in DbSet<Element<T>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, code-first

I have a Domain as described below;

Can I configure EntityFramework to have a single table for `Elements` and a single table for both `ItemA` and `ItemB`???

```
public class Element<T> where T : ItemBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemA : ItemBase
{
    ItemA(Guid id, string name): base(id, name)
}

public class ItemB : ItemBase
{
    ItemB(Guid id, string name): base(id, name)
}

public class ItemBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Can I configure

So far the only suggestion that makes any sense is to use a `[Table]` attribute on the `Element` class but I'm sure there's a better way configuring `DbSet<>` correctly...